# Proof of a property of a cofactor matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ is a matrix with $n\geq2$, prove the following property of its cofactor matrix - 
$ {cof} (A^t) = ({cof} (A))^t$.

Are the following properties of matrices and determinants of use here -

(a) $ \det(A^t)=\det(A)$;

(b) $(A^{-1})^t=(A^t)^{-1}$;

(c) $ A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}(cof(A))^t$.

Comment: found the proof. take transpose of (c) and make use of a,b and c to get the desired equality.

Comment: Where did you find the proof?